# how to make tauri app window have rounded corners with window vibrancy

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, tauri

I'm trying to make calculator with tauri but the problem with window vibrancy having square corners.

I tried to change **hRgnBlur** argument and also I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787966/winapi-dwmapi-blur-behind-window-with-irregular-shape) but couldn't do it in rust.
I tried CreateRoundRectRgn and SetWindowRgn but got big white borders around the window

```
let hdc: HDC = HDC::default();
BeginPath(hdc);
AngleArc(hdc, 0, 0, 20, 0.0, 0.0);
EndPath(hdc);
let bb = DWM_BLURBEHIND {
    dwFlags: 1,
    fEnable: true.into(),
    hRgnBlur: PathToRegion(hdc),
    fTransitionOnMaximized: true.into(),
};
let _ = DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, &bb);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slfSJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not supported (`DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`) in windows 10 only 7/Vista. I Used both of `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` and `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` but `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` seemed to not doing the blur. Sadly there is no option to customize the region.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into making fully transparent windows and then do rounded corners using CSS?

Here're some resources for you:

1. [Window Customization](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/window-customization/)
2. [Window Vibrancy Plugin](https://github.com/tauri-apps/window-vibrancy) especially for Windows
3. [Custom Window tutorial](https://www.developermindset.com/tauri-custom-window-and-custom-font/)

And code from Tauri's docs:

```
<div data-tauri-drag-region class="titlebar">
  <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-minimize">
    <img
      src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:window-minimize.svg"
      alt="minimize"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-maximize">
    <img
      src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:window-maximize.svg"
      alt="maximize"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-close">
    <img src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:close.svg" alt="close" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.titlebar {
  height: 30px;
  background: #329ea3;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.titlebar-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.titlebar-button:hover {
  background: #5bbec3;
}
```

Comment: I found a problem in ```DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow``` method that is it does work at all. The Real WORKING method was ```SetWindowCompositionAttribute```.

Comment: `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` is not working with windows 8 or later. Only 7/Vista therefore  `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` will only work.

Comment: Is there any work around?